# Multiline list output in doctest

Tags: python, list, multiline, doctest

I'm testing the result of a function, which returns a list of long strings. Since I have line size limitations, I can't have the whole list on one line.

I already tried printing the list and that works, but I was wondering if there was another way without having to print the result of the function. What I got:

```
def my_function(input):
    r"""Some description.

        >>> import pprint
        >>> pprint.pprint(my_function("input"))
        ['long_string_1',
         'long_string_2',
         'long_string_3']
    """
    return list_of_long_strings
```

Is it possible to do this without printing, just calling the function and having the list with backlashes or something?

Comment: One way to do it is *comparison*, `>>> my_function("input") == [ ... ]` `True`

Comment: Not sure what you want ?

Comment: @JasonYang Just wanted to see what options I have for multiline lists in addition to printing as I haven't been able to find official guidelines on how to handle multiline output in doctest

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```py
def my_function(input):
    r"""Some description.

        >>> my_function("input") == ['long_string_1',
        ...     'long_string_2', 'long_string_3']
        True
    """
    list_of_long_strings = ['long_string_1', 'long_string_2', 'long_string_3']
    return list_of_long_strings
```